# Hyperlink navigation - inside code files

Tags: ide, code-organization

Does anyone know if there's an existing plugin / system for setting up hyperlink-style navigation inside a code file?  I've been dealing with some overly large files recently, and I was thinking it'd be nice to set up a javadoc-style list of function names up top in a block comment, with some kind of editor plugin to jump to the appropriate line number.

What I don't know, is if that sort of behavior is already present in any popular IDE *or* available in any plugins.  I think it'd be a fairly useful tool, but I don't want to go through the effort of writing a plugin if it's already been written.

Apologies if this is slightly off topic, it seems too specific for programmers.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) (my favourite IDE) offers Ctrl+Click navigation since long ago.

You ctrl+click on a name of class or function or variable and IDEA takes you to its definition.

It also has "jump to file member" functionality, which, I think, is more than you're looking for (because you can invoke it from any place in a file).

Comment: Interesting - I'll have to take a look at that one.

Comment: Most IDEs do that.  (VS requires the PPT)